# Image gallery in CollectionViewController

Tags: xcode, image, gallery

I am recently working on an iphone app in xcode 6 and created an image gallery in CollectionViewControllor, I need help about 2 things;

first I need to get a fullscreen view of the Images I have in each cell,
second How I can update the images dynamically

I really appreciate your help in advance,

Answer (score 0):

A few suggestions on the two questions in this post

1. How to show image in full screen? Depends how you want it to show to user. One way could be to make a new view controller having a UIImage. Once you tap on the image in collection view (using didSelectItemAtIndexPath), you can pass the image to new controller which displays it.
2. To update the images in real time, I assume you have images stored somewhere remotely and want to fetch those in background and update the collection view. Following article may help over here

http://www.raywenderlich.com/19788/how-to-use-nsoperations-and-nsoperationqueues

Hope it helps.